# How to toggle class in option of multiselect?

Tags: jquery, html

I have select list with 1500+ option as:

```
<select multiselect="multiselect" class="cssClass">
   <option value="ID1">Text</option>
   <option value="ID2">Text</option>
   <option value="ID3">Text</option>
   <option value="ID4">Text</option>
   <option value="ID">Text</option>
   .
   .
</select>
```

On click on an option I want to toggle class `ItemSelected` for selected option and for this I don't want to loop through all option as it is a large number list.

**NOTE**

Here I'm allowing to select multiple option. How could get only clicked option and toggle class only for that option?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but... 1500+ options? That does sound like a list that is not user-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop on everything. Just use the following `eventHandler`:

```
$(".cssClass option").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("ItemSelected");
});
```

You can see a working snippet here:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".cssClass option").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("ItemSelected");
  });
});
```

```css
.cssClass {width: 100px;}
.cssClass option {padding: 5px;}
.cssClass .ItemSelected {background: #99f;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiselect="multiselect" class="cssClass" size="5">
  <option value="ID1">Text</option>
  <option value="ID2">Text</option>
  <option value="ID3">Text</option>
  <option value="ID4">Text</option>
  <option value="ID5">Text</option>
</select>
```

Since it focuses, you can also `blur()` once selected:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".cssClass option").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("ItemSelected");
    $(".cssClass").blur();
  });
});
```

```css
.cssClass {width: 100px;}
.cssClass option {padding: 5px;}
.cssClass .ItemSelected {background: #99f;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiselect="multiselect" class="cssClass" size="5">
  <option value="ID1">Text</option>
  <option value="ID2">Text</option>
  <option value="ID3">Text</option>
  <option value="ID4">Text</option>
  <option value="ID5">Text</option>
</select>
```

Or unselect the selection:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".cssClass option").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("ItemSelected");
    $(".cssClass").val("-1");
  });
});
```

```css
.cssClass {width: 100px;}
.cssClass option {padding: 5px;}
.cssClass .ItemSelected {background: #99f;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiselect="multiselect" class="cssClass" size="5">
  <option value="ID1">Text</option>
  <option value="ID2">Text</option>
  <option value="ID3">Text</option>
  <option value="ID4">Text</option>
  <option value="ID5">Text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unable to toggle class, even not adding class to selected option.

Comment: @Kaishu Did you run the above snippet? It works. I can see the change of colour.

Comment: Yes, I have tested again it do nothing in my case...!

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly adjusted the HTML, the select has an ID now.

```
<div class="parent" style="width:100px; overflow:hidden;">
  <select id="demo" multiselect="multiselect" class="cssClass">
    <option value="ID1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="ID2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="ID3">Text 3</option>
    <option value="ID4">Text 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Using the following jQuery should solve your issue:

```
$("#demo").change (function() {
  $("#demo option:selected").toggleClass("ItemSelected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

For this example, it adds font bold to the class ItemSelected to make it visually clear that the class is added and removed.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".cssClass", function(){
    $(this).find("option").removeClass("ItemSelected");
    $(this).find("option:selected").addClass("ItemSelected");
})
```

```css
.ItemSelected {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" class="cssClass">
   <option value="ID1">Text</option>
   <option value="ID2">Text</option>
   <option value="ID3">Text</option>
   <option value="ID4">Text</option>
   <option value="ID">Text</option>
   
   
</select>
```